# How to save IMAP email body text with Get-IMAP NetCmdlets in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, imap

I am trying to capture the message body text for multipart and plain text emails using netcmdlets. The connection works successfully and emails are fetched and I am able to save attachments without a problem, but I do not know how to save the body text.

```
import-module "C:\Program Files\nsoftware\NetCmdlets V4\netcmdlets"

$emails = get-imap -Connect $imapconnection -Folder $folder
foreach($msg in $emails)
{
    if($msg.ContentType.StartsWith("multipart"))
    {
        # get message body text for multipart?
    }
    else
    {
        # get message body text for non multipart??
    }
}
```

**edit**

```
get-imap -Connect $imapconnection -Folder $folder | Get-Member
```

gives

```
TypeName: nsoftware.NetCmdlets.Commands.MessageInfoObject

Name                MemberType Definition
----                ---------- ----------
Equals              Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode         Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType             Method     type GetType()
ToString            Method     string ToString()
BCC                 Property   string[] BCC {get;set;}
CC                  Property   string[] CC {get;set;}
ContentEncoding     Property   string ContentEncoding {get;set;}
ContentType         Property   string ContentType {get;set;}
Date                Property   string Date {get;set;}
Flags               Property   string Flags {get;set;}
From                Property   string From {get;set;}
FromEmail           Property   string FromEmail {get;set;}
FromFriendlyName    Property   string FromFriendlyName {get;set;}
Id                  Property   string Id {get;set;}
PartContentEncoding Property   string[] PartContentEncoding {get;set;}
PartContentType     Property   string[] PartContentType {get;set;}
PartCount           Property   int PartCount {get;set;}
PartFileName        Property   string[] PartFileName {get;set;}
PartId              Property   string[] PartId {get;set;}
PartMultiPartMode   Property   string[] PartMultiPartMode {get;set;}
PartParameters      Property   string[] PartParameters {get;set;}
PartSize            Property   string[] PartSize {get;set;}
ReplyTo             Property   string ReplyTo {get;set;}
ReplyToEmail        Property   string ReplyToEmail {get;set;}
ReplyToFriendlyName Property   string ReplyToFriendlyName {get;set;}
Size                Property   long Size {get;set;}
Subject             Property   string Subject {get;set;}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with those cmdlets. Can you use `$msg | Get-Member` to see if any of the properties look like the body content? You might need to drill down a little. The documentation indicates a few different output types.

Comment: added output to question

Comment: `$msg | Get-Member` on its own returns a blank line (added to the foreach loop)

Answer (score 0):

Fetching all of the messages from a folder will return a collection of MessageInfoObjects, but to grab the email body itself you'll need to fetch a specific message by passing the message Id to the -View parameter.  You can grab the Id from the MessageInfoObject, so you might have some logic like this:

```
$emailList = Get-IMAP -Connection $conn -Folder INBOX
$currentEmail = Get-IMAP -Connection $conn -Folder INBOX -View $emailList[0].Id
```

At this point $currentEmail.Text will return the body for that message (the first message in the inbox).